# Powerquery: split multi-value cell to below empty cells

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am importing a lot of tables from pdf-files into Excel by Powerquery - which works pretty well.

Beside several other migrations I have the following task which I am not able to solve:

In some cases - esp. after page breaks - single values that should go into single cells (one below the other) are placed into one cell joined by linebreaks and below cells are empty.

[image: sample of cell with multi-value and expected result]

I need to split the values of such a cell (cell-content contains line-breaks) and put 2nd to n value into the according empty cells below this cell.

(It's kind of a "splitted drill-down" ...)

I am pretty new to M (not to VBA or programming) but I am not able to find a working solution.

Comment: Delete the null rows, then split the values to a list using the relevant delimiter, then expand the list to new rows.

Comment: That's not possible: to the right are more values that are different per each row - if I delete the null rows I would loose these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to do robustly but you can expand using `Text.Split` on the line feed delimiter as @horseyride suggests and remove the blank rows on that second column and then smash the columns back together with `Table.FromColumns`.

Here's an example you can paste into the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUUoEYkMDpVgdCDcJiI0gXCMgMxkkawrnpsTkpcbkpYEEjeCCIJ4FMs8IImcMZKaDJI3h3AwQ11wpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Week = _t, A = _t, B = _t]),
    TransformA = List.Select(List.Combine(List.Transform(Source[A], each Text.Split(_, "#(lf)"))), each Text.Length(_) > 0),
    FromCols = Table.FromColumns({Source[Week], TransformA, Source[B]}, {"Week", "A", "B"})
in
    FromCols
```

This takes a starting table like this:
[image: Start]

Transforms the `A` column as a list, splitting each element on the line feed character, combining each result back together, and filtering out null and empty strings:

[image: Transform]

The final step takes columns `Week` and `B` from the original table and sticks the transformed column `A` in the middle:

[image: Result]

You'll run into trouble if the number of extra expanded rows doesn't exactly match the number of blank rows removed but this should work under the assumption that they do match.

Comment: Perfect :-) The only thing I had to change: replace null by "" before split. As far as I can see, the number of blank rows alwasy maps to the number of values in the multi-value-cell. Well - I have to learn this way of M-thinking - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

right click column

transform data type text

right click column ... split column ... by delimiter ... advanced option, split using special characters [x] .. split into rows

[image]

then use arrow atop that column to filter out null rows

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column2"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Delimiter", each ([Column2] <> null)),
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work - it adds new rows to the table - but I need the values in the existing cells below. I updated the image to reflect this point

Comment: again how many columns do you have to apply the split and move? If just one, its probably easy to rebuild the table by filtering, then appending that column to the original set