# Table.Column with value (-4.80, 0.70) throws error when using as List

Tags: powerquery, m

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68625162/16578424 I am able to clean up a lot of data.

But now I have to fix a column that contains a cell with the value of `(-4.80, 0.70)` which returns an error when calling the column-function within my function
[image: Source table and result]

To me the error message sounds like if `(-4.80, 0.70)` is read as a list with two columns - and that throws the error :-/

This is the function.
I commented everything out - and added the first two rows to demonstrate the problem.

```
//fnFixMultipleValuesInCell
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/68625162/1657842
let
    fnFixMultipleValuesInCell = (Source as table, columnName as text, columnIndex as number) as table =>
    let

        listColumn = Table.Column(Source, columnName), //same result for  listColumn = Source[Column2]
        Result = Table.FromList(listColumn)   /*,
        

        addIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index",0),
        replaceNull = Table.ReplaceValue(addIndex,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{columnName}),

        splitMergedCells = List.Select(List.Combine(List.Transform( Table.Column(replaceNull, columnName), each Text.Split(_, "#(lf)"))), each Text.Length(_) > 0 ),
        
        insertColumn = Table.AddColumn(replaceNull, "new", each splitMergedCells{[Index]}) ,

        removeOldColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(insertColumn,{columnName, "Index"}),
        renameColumn = Table.RenameColumns(removeOldColumn,{{"new",columnName}}),
        ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(renameColumn),
        newColumnNamesList = List.RemoveLastN( List.Combine({List.FirstN(ColumnNames, columnIndex-2), List.LastN(ColumnNames,1), List.LastN(ColumnNames, List.Count(ColumnNames)-columnIndex+1 ) } ),1),
        Result = Table.ReorderColumns(renameColumn, newColumnNamesList) */

    in
        Result
in fnFixMultipleValuesInCell
```

Anything wrong with my code?
Anything I can do, to use this function for any kind of column - regardless of the data?

Comment: Why do you have your code as a screenshot?  Why not post it as text to make it easy for people to help you?

Comment: Sorry, you are right - I changed to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is interpreting the comma as denoting an extra column.

If you look at the documentation for [Table.FromList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fromlist), you'll see the following:

```
Table.FromList(list as list, optional splitter as nullable function, optional columns as any, optional default as any, optional extraValues as nullable number) as table
```

> Converts a list, `list` into a table by applying the optional splitting function, `splitter`, to each item in the list. ***By default, the list is assumed to be a list of text values that is split by commas.*** Optional columns may be the number of `columns`, a list of columns or a TableType. Optional `default` and `extraValues` may also be specified.

To fix this, change `Table.FromList(listColumn)` to

```
Table.FromList(listColumn, Splitter.SplitByNothing())
```

Comment: Many thanks! To be honest, I haven't read the documentation. But now it is clear. Knowing that, I will have to review the whole code.